# Difference between running a test with RunWith(Junit4::class) annotation and without it

Tags: java, android

I tried running a particular test without @RunWith(JUnit4::class) annotation and it did seem to work.

What is the significance of the @RunWith annotation here? What difference does it make and what value does it add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Simple Words** - We can use a custom test runner by annotating our test class with the **@RunWith** annotation.

If a test class doesn’t have this annotation, JUnit 4 runs it by using the default test runner that is called the BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.

JUnit Runners are highly adaptable and let the developer change the test execution procedure and the whole test process.

For example, suites in JUnit 4 are built using RunWith, and a custom runner named Suite:

```
 @RunWith(Suite.class)
 @SuiteClasses({ATest.class, BTest.class, CTest.class})
 public class ABCSuite {
 }
```